# Coinbase Pro API with Delphi ( Invalid signature)

Tags: rest, api, delphi, get, coinbase-api

I am trying to make a "get" request to Coinbase Pro with Delphi 10.3 and the rest components 
as described in the documentation https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#api-key-permissions.

I always get the following message back: invalid signature.
I've checked everything several times but I can't find the error. Maybe it is a problem
with the Base64 de/encoding to a string from the secret key and the CB-ACCESS-SIGN header?
The sha256 HMAC encoding and the timestamp seems to work well. 
The remaining headers also seem to be all right.

Here is my code. The keys are old ones and only as an example:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,IdHashSha, Vcl.StdCtrls,IdSSLOpenSSL,IdGlobal,IdHMAC,IdHMACSHA1,
  REST.Types, Data.Bind.Components, Data.Bind.ObjectScope,  REST.Client,EncdDecd,system.netencoding,json,idcoder,idcodermime;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Button2: TButton;
    RESTClient1: TRESTClient;
    RESTRequest1: TRESTRequest;
    RESTResponse1: TRESTResponse;
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }

 function CalculateHMACSHA256(const value, skey: String): String;
 function DateTimeToUnix(ConvDate: TDateTime): Longint;
 function GetCurrentDateTime: TDateTime;
 procedure stringcreate;

end;
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  timestamp:string;
  date:tdatetime;
  skeydecode:string;
  sha256:string;
  encode:string;
  prehash:string;
  implementation
const UnixStartDate: TDateTime = 25569.0;
const skey:string='iG8mrRLIT9EGw0gMxjxo55U74RtAQeSUal28+VR+STmWvtrTGNunfL19M9M3mmPpBsJLu7LZmrFskb3q42ditQ==';
const apikey:string='3a829c8b4bddb75fb372183a5f63f2a4';
const passphrase:string='eevj5njvs65';


{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  jValue:TJSONValue;

begin
stringcreate;
restclient1.BaseURL:='https://api.pro.coinbase.com/accounts';
restrequest1.Params.AddHeader('CB-ACCESS-KEY',apikey);
restrequest1.Params.AddHeader('CB-ACCESS-SIGN',encode);
restrequest1.Params.AddHeader('CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP',timestamp);
restrequest1.Params.AddHeader('CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE',passphrase);

RESTRequest1.Execute;
jValue:=RESTResponse1.JSONValue;
edit1.Text:= jValue.ToString;
end;

function tform1.CalculateHMACSHA256(const value, skey: String): String;
var
hmac: TIdHMACSHA256;
hash: TIdBytes;
begin
LoadOpenSSLLibrary;
if not TIdHashSHA256.IsAvailable then
showmessage('Error');
hmac := TIdHMACSHA256.Create;
try
hmac.Key := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8.GetBytes(skey);
hash := hmac.HashValue(IndyTextEncoding_UTF8.GetBytes(value));
Result := ToHex(hash);
finally
hmac.Free;
end;
end;

function tform1.DateTimeToUnix(ConvDate: TDateTime): Longint;
begin
 Result := Round((ConvDate - UnixStartDate) * 86400);
end;

 function tform1.GetCurrentDateTime: TDateTime;
var
  SystemTime: TSystemTime;
begin
  GetSystemTime(SystemTime);
  Result := system.SysUtils.Systemtimetodatetime(SystemTime);
end;

procedure tform1.stringcreate;
begin
date:=strtodatetime(system.SysUtils.DateTimeToStr(GetCurrentDateTime));
timestamp:=inttostr(DateTimeToUnix(date));
skeydecode:=TIdDecoderMIME.DecodeString(skey);
prehash:=timestamp+'GET'+'/accounts';
sha256:=CalculateHMACSHA256(prehash ,skeydecode);
encode:=Tidencodermime.EncodeString(sha256);

end;


end.
```

Please can you help me?